# "Derived" field resolver for GraphQL using Hot Chocolate and EFCore

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I am working on a GraphQL endpoint using ASP.NET 5, Hot Chocolate and EFCore 5. I have entity framework entities that I'm exposing in GraphQL using Hot Chocolate. I have a need to "derive" one of the fields. Say for example I have a class called employee and it has FirstName and LastName properties. I want the GraphQL endpoint to expose a "FullName" field for the employee that will internally concatenate the first and last name. Note that FirstName and LastName values exist as columns of the Employee database table but the "FullName" field will be derived. How do I go about doing this? I attempted this as follows and it's not working

```cs
public class EmployeeType : ObjectType<Employee>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Employee> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(@"FullName")
            .Type<StringType>()
            .ResolveWith<Resolvers>( p => p.GetFullName(default!, default!) )
            .UseDbContext<AppDbContext>()
            .Description(@"Full name of the employee");
    }

    private class Resolvers
    {
        public string GetFullName(Employee e, [ScopedService] AppDbContext context)
        {
            return e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

The FullName field does show up in the GraphQL query but it is always blank. I think the Employee instance e that is passed into GetFullName() has empty string values for the first and last name.

How do I fix this? Is this the right approach to the problem?

Comment: My implementation looks similar to yours except that I not used StringType yet. I made some experiments (with StringType too) but couldn't find anything that is wrong with your code. Did you try BananaCake Popup to evaluate queries - what does it tell about the field. The only theory I have is that wording may make a difference ("fullName" vs. "FullName"). Omitting [Parent] did not make a difference for me, but is a good idea to add it anyhow (see answer from Tobias Tengler).

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't use `ResolveWith` myself often, I'm pretty sure you'd have to annotate the `Employee` using the `ParentAttribute`:

```cs
public string GetFullName([Parent] Employee e, [ScopedService] AppDbContext context)
{
    return e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName;
}
```

[Learn more about this in the resolver documentation](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/resolvers/#accessing-parent-values)

Comment: Worked for me thank you!

Comment: Using this method, the FirstName and LastName must be included in the original graphQL query, otherwise their values will be null. Is there anyway to ensure that these dependent fields are always included when querying for the FullName?

Comment: @PeterKerr did you find an answer? I'm also facing similar issue.

Comment: You can mark fields that should always be projected to the data source via `IsProjected(true)`. There isn't an API yet to define dependencies like "Always and only project Y, when X is selected".

Comment: Thanks @TobiasTengler, is that feature likely to be added anytime soon?

Comment: It is not planned for v13 as far as I'm aware, but changes to the projection engine are planned so maybe it will be added in one of the releases after v13, but I can't make any promises just yet.